# How to prevent loop when setValue from store in radio button?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms

In reactive form I have radio buttons. 
During initialization one of them is selected base on data from store by setValue.
When I change radio button by setValue - form.valueChanges is running and dispatch new action, but after that the infinite loop starts.

There is some way to checked radio button without event or prevent valueChanges?

[image]

How to selected radio button without execute valueChanges or prevent loop when value was change?

Comment: Please provide a running example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setValue with options. something like this

```
form.setValue(value, {emitEvent: false})
```

Comment: Sorry, @andrzejI have a mistake in answer. I have updated the answer the options is the second argument of `.setValue` method.